# Clustering on this reinforcement learning approach?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to create an agent that selects an action depending on a state that gives back maximum reward.

To keep things simple I will keep it to two actions and 24 different states.

The states is to mimic hours in a day and the two actions are certain web pages displayed to the user.

I am still trying to figure out how the reward will be given and how the policy will look depending on the reward. The most plausible is the following:

between 0 and 1 will determine 100% of the probability. Which action should most likely be taken is the one with the most chance of reward.

### Very simple example for the same state x:

If the user is shown page 1(action) and stays on it (the action) then a reward is due for page one.

x = amount of rewards given for this state for page 1 = 1
y = amount of rewards given for this state for page 2 = 0

page 1 + page 2 = 1.0 
chance x = ((x+y)/x) = 1/1 = 1.0 
chance y = ((x+y)/y) = 1/0 = 0.0 
1.0 chance that page 1 is the correct action for that state
0.0 chance that page 2 is the correct action for that state

The user is shown page 1(action) due to the risk of reward being higher if displaying page 1 at this state. However if the user navigates instead to page 2, then page 2 will get a reward.

x = amount of rewards given for this state for page 1 = 1
y = amount of rewards given for this state for page 2 = 1

page 1 + page 2 = 1.0 
chance x = ((x+y)/x) = 2/1 = 0.5
chance y = ((x+y)/y) = 2/1 = 0.5 
0.5 chance that page 1 is the correct action for that state
0.5 chance that page 2 is the correct action for that state

If the user is shown page 1(action) and stays on page 1, page 1 will get another reward.

x = amount of rewards given for this state for page 1 = 2
y = amount of rewards given for this state for page 2 = 1

page 1 + page 2 = 1.0 
chance x = 1.0 / ((x+y)*x) = 1.0 / 3*2 = 2/3
chance y = 1.0 / ((x+y)*x) = 1.0 / 3*1 = 1/3
2/3 chance that page 1 is the correct action for that state
1/3 chance that page 2 is the correct action for that state

As you see it updates and learns.

### Clustering

This will however only work if all days are the same, and we know that they aren't. User might use page 1 week one and the next week page 2 and the week after that page 1 and so one. So finding a pattern is also needed somehow.

### What I am trying to achieve

I have the following input data (state):

```
{
    location: 'Möllevångstorget, 21424, Malmö',
    weekday: 'monday',
    time: '07:31'
}
```

Alternatively:

```
{
    lat: 55.591538,
    lon: 13.007153,
    timestamp: '2015-03-03 07:31'
}
```

Or:

```
{
    lat: 55.591538,
    lon: 13.007153,
    timestamp: 1427864271 // unix epoch time
}
```

As you can see, you can manipulate the inputs. It's important though to include location and when this occurred.

As mentioned before, finding patterns is what I'm most worried about. I wish to predict when a user is going to use the application (displayed the page), the state is created when the user uses the application.

Another problem I can see is that let's say the user uses the application at 07:30 one week, then uses it 07:35 the next and the third week uses it 07:32 all from *around* the same location, the algorithm should be able to determine that the user(environment) will pick a specific page(action).

Basically predicting what action the user is going to choose.

Comment: Please **don't cross post**: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144275/clustering-on-this-reinforcement-learning-approach

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you should use clustering. You will just need to implement good function approximation. If you have geo’s, just reverse encode that to country. Then use country & city as a state inputs, e.g.: your features might end up being:

`is_america
is_africa
is_middle_east
is_new_york
is_morning
is_afternoon
etc`

If your country and city list grows too big considering doing it via [relational reinforcement learning](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=relational+reinforcement+learning&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ei=UyklVbrmL-Oz7Aac9IGIAQ&ved=0CBsQgQMwAA)